# Binding a ComboBox entirely in XAML

Tags: silverlight, binding

I have a ComboBox on a silverlight control, that I want to bind. Sounds simple, except what I'm finding is that because the data for the ItemsSource comes from a web service asynchronously, I need to use the code behind to bind the SelectedValue only after the data has come back.

The collection that the data goes in implements INotifyCollectionChanged and INotifyPropertyChanged, so it should all be working, and indeed the combo box loads properly, but there is no value pre-selected.

What I think is happening is that the SelectedValue is getting bound before the collection has loaded - when the combobox is empty - so nothing is selected, and then later when the data comes in, the combobox is populated, but it is not checking the selected value again.

So whilst I have this working if I use code behind to hook up events and creating bindings in code, I'd like to move this all to XAML with something like:

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,3,9,127" Name="cboCategoryID"  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"
           ItemsSource="{StaticResource Categories}"
           SelectedValue="{Binding CategoryID, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
           SelectedValuePath="CategoryID" 
           DisplayMemberPath="Caption"
           VerticalAlignment="Center">
</ComboBox>
```

This correctly loads items, but doesn't bind the selected value. If I put the following code in the code-behind, it all works:

```
public MainControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    CategoryCollection cats = new CategoryCollection();
    cats.Dispatcher = this.Dispatcher;
    cats.LoadComplete += new EventHandler(cats_LoadComplete);
    cboCategoryID.ItemsSource = cats;
    cats.LoadAll();
}

private void cats_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cboCategoryID.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, new System.Windows.Data.Binding("CategoryID"));
}
```

Is there a way to do this without resorting to code behind?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using mvvm? If so, you can try to set the ItemsSource and SelectedItem in the callback of the web service, or take a look at this post from Kyle.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/06/18/combobox-sample-for-ria-services.aspx

Comment: My web service doesn't have a callback as such, at least not one that can see the UI layer. I'll check out the link you posted though, it looks like perhaps that extension library can help.

Answer (score 0):

you are already using a collection that notifies of changes, so if the value that you are binding the SelectedValue to is notifying of changes, then all you have to do is set that property after the values are loaded from the webservice.  it SHOULD update the combobox automatically, allowing you to do your binding purely in xaml.

```
public myObject CategoryID { get {....} 
                             set {
                              this.categoryID = value;
                              RaisePropertyChanged("CategoryID");}


public void DataLoadedHandler()
{
    CategoryID = 34; // this will cause the binding to update
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but I would rather not have to set the value of the property manually. That kinda defeats the purpose of binding it

Comment: you  must be setting/getting the "categoryid" from somewhere. how is the model supposed to know that it is, if you dont set it?

Comment: Oh I see. Yes, you are correct. The DataContext is downloaded from a web service, so the properties are set when the result comes back. Where that happens though, has no access to the UI layer.

Comment: @ChOOk if it has access to the data layer, all you have to do is make a depnd prop and set it in the code, bind selected item to it in the xaml

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this simple sample:
XAML:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:sdk="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackoverflowQuestions.Silverlight" xmlns:sdk1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk" x:Class="StackoverflowQuestions.Silverlight.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Item">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyToBeWatched}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <!--<sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" RowStyle="{StaticResource Style1}">
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PropertyToBeWatched}" Header="Property1"/>
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        </sdk:DataGrid>-->
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Item}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Codebehind:
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private ObservableCollection _myList;
            private CustomClass _selectedItem;

```
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public ObservableCollection<CustomClass> MyList
        {
            get { return _myList ?? (_myList = new ObservableCollection<CustomClass>()); }
            set
            {
                _myList = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("MyList");
            }
        }

        public CustomClass SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            }
        }

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyname)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;

            MyList.Add(new CustomClass() { PropertyToBeWatched = "1"});
            MyList.Add(new CustomClass() { PropertyToBeWatched = "2" });
            MyList.Add(new CustomClass() { PropertyToBeWatched = "2" });
            MyList.Add(new CustomClass() { PropertyToBeWatched = "2" });

            SelectedItem = MyList[1]; //Here is where it happens
        }

    }
```

By binding the SelectedItem of the ComboBox to an entity, we can achieve what you want. This works TwoWay ofcourse.

Hope this helps. :D

Comment: This is using code behind, which I was hoping to avoid. And doesn't manually setting the SelectedItem kinda defeat the purpose of binding?

Comment: Why would it defeat the purpose of binding? the viewmodel is allowed to manipulate data in the MVVM pattern, thats exactly it purpose, right?